# Knockout.js if statement boolean test

Tags: javascript, if-statement, knockout.js

I have an observable that can etiher have false (default), or an object as value.
Following code block arranges the html structure according to the value of the observable

```
      <!-- ko: if peer() -->
        <div id="chatbox" >
            <div id="textbox">Should be invisible</div>
        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko: ifnot peer()  -->
        <div id="banner" >Should be visible</div>
        <!-- /ko -->
```

and the observable is defined as

```
   function T(){
      this.peer = ko.observable(false);
   };
   ko.applyBindings(new T());
```

Both "Should be visible" and "Should be invisible" are displayed on page. I also tried without the "()" in if conditions, but the outcome is still the same. Please see http://jsfiddle.net/zSKhN/

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have just placed the colons wrong. `ko: if` should be `ko if:` and so on, the markup should look like this:

```
<!-- ko if: peer() -->
<div id="chatbox" >
  <div id="textbox">Should be invisible</div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko ifnot: peer()  -->
<div id="banner" >Should be visible</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Here's an updated jsfiddle of your example: http://jsfiddle.net/zSKhN/

Comment: No problem. Details like that are easy to miss when you're stuck, happens to me on a daily basis :)